# JavaScript Ordering List of Dates in Descending Order

Tags: javascript, function, sorting

The dates look like this:

```
[‘Oct 7, 2009’, ‘Nov 10, 2009’, ‘Jan 10, 2009’, ‘Oct 22, 2009’, …]
```

The month is always the first three characters of full month name (‘January’ => ‘Jan’, ‘February’ => ‘Feb’, …).

The day is one or two digits (1, 2, … 31), with no preceding zero.

There is always a comma after the day. The year is always four digits.

I'm trying to write a function that will order this list of string in date by descending order

This is what I have currently:

```
let dates = [
'Oct 7, 2009',
'Nov 10, 2009',
'Jan 10, 2009',
'Oct 22, 2009'
]

let sortDate = function (date1, date2) {
  if (date1 > date2) return -1
  if (date1 < date2) return 1
  return 0
}

dates.sort(sortDate)

for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  document.write(i + ': ' + dates[i])
}
```

The output shows this though:

```
0: Oct 7, 2009
1: Oct 22, 2009
2: Nov 10, 2009
3: Jan 10, 2009
```

January should be first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `sort` callback, return the difference of the dates expressed in epochs (number of milliseconds). You can use [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for this:

```
    return Date.parse(date1) - Date.parse(date2);
```

```js
let dates = ['Oct 7, 2009', 'Nov 10, 2009', 'Jan 10, 2009', 'Oct 22, 2009'];

let sortDate = function (date1, date2) {
  return Date.parse(date1) - Date.parse(date2);
}

dates.sort(sortDate)

for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  console.log(i + ': ' + dates[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're sorting on alphanumeric order not in date order, because you're comparing strings. You need to convert those strings to [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) before sorting.

```
dates.map(date => {
  arr = date.match(/([a-zA-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{4})/);
  return new Date(arr[3], months.indexOf(arr[1]), arr[2]);
});
```

Where `dates` is your date array and `months` is an ordered array of months.

And then in your comparison function compare `date.valueOf()`, which is the Date represented in milliseconds since Unix epoch